# Invalid bind expression type of Id for column of type Decimal

Tags: trigger

```
public class handler {
    list<id> list1 = new list<id>();

    public void idnum(list<product__c>prolist) {
        for(product__c pro: prolist) {
            list1.add(pro.Opp__c);
        }

        list<opportunity>opplist  = [
            select id, name, stagename, closedate, num__c, (
                select id, name, Opp__c, Parent_id__c 
                from products__r
            ) 
            from opportunity 
            where num__c in :list1
        ];

        for(opportunity opp: opplist) {
            for(product__c pro:opp.products__r) {
                opp.num__c = pro.Parent_id__c;
            }
        }

        update opplist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Including code is (usually) important to help others understand what your problem is and to show that you aren't asking people to do your work for you. Including code (and nothing else), however, usually doesn't make a very good question. This question would be improved (and likely have gotten a more positive response) if you had included additional details like _what_ you've tried so far, and _what_ research you've done to this point. Including full error messages (along with the stack trace) is also a generally good idea.

Answer (score 3):

You have a bind expression `:list1` in your SOQL query. You declare this variable `list1` as a `list<id>`, but the field `num__c` against which you are comparing it is typed as some numerical type (number, currency, percentage).

Since those types aren't comparable, you get a compile-time error.

If `Product2.Opp__c` is a lookup to Opportunity, you probably need to change your SOQL to `where Id in :list1`.

Comment: yes i did but the field was not updated

Comment: Please stick to one question per post. Before you open your next one, consider taking a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can formulate a detailed, specific description of what you're trying to do and what is not working. It'll help you get good help faster.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty straight forward. List1 is type `List<id>` and you are using it a a filter on a number field `num__c`

Change

```
from opportunity where num__c in :list1
```

to

```
from opportunity where Id in :list1
```

Comment: if i use string then it will be ok?

Comment: Updated my answer to show you.

Comment: yes i did but field was not updated

Comment: That's two different questions. The first is why are you getting the error which my post answers. If you update your code and the error goes away please select my answer. If you have a second question about why your value is not updating, please ask a new question for additional help.

Comment: error was gone but though it was not updating the field

Comment: Right, so select one of the answers and open a new question about your new issue.

Comment: @vinaykumarsadineni I have already written up an answer to your second question. I just need you to ask it.